# Installing Anki 2.0.42 breaks graphical display on fresh Ubuntu 16.04 install - xdg-mime related?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, unity, xdg, anki

Installing the 64 bit Anki deb file (v2.0.42) on my Dell Inspiron 5423, running Ubuntu 14.04 or Ubuntu 16.04, seems to break the desktop (details and photo below). I have only been able to fix the problem by reinstalling Ubuntu.

**Why is this happening? How can I fix this problem without having to reinstall Ubuntu? Ideally, how can I get Anki v2.0.42 working on my laptop?**

The cleanest example of this problem:

- Format the / partition, I install Ubuntu 16.04 and update/upgrade
- Download the Anki deb file from https://apps.ankiweb.net/
- Eextract it and install it as described on the webpage (ultimately running sudo make install)
- This causes my Unity desktop to be visually corrupted and forces a restart
- On booting I am presented with the login screen, when I attempt to login I see a visual corruption of the login screen (photo below) and then the login screen shows again

[image: Corrupted login screen]

This problem has happened both times I've install it on Ubuntu 16.04. I was also running Ubuntu 14.04 and encountered the same issue when I installed Anki v2.0.42 there.

Looking at the [Makefile](https://github.com/dae/anki/blob/master/Makefile) I am wondering about the xdg-mime lines. **Could these be the root cause? What do they do?**

Running `sudo make uninstall` or the following commands manually does not fix the problem:

`xdg-mime uninstall /usr/local/share/mime/packages/anki.xml
-xdg-mime uninstall /usr/local/share/mime/packages/anki.xml`

Answer (score -1):

I have the exact same problem. The login in screen even looks the same.

I also could not solve without a fresh install. I can confirm however that variations of **purging, updating, changing nvidia and nouveau drivers** (after reaching the login screen and then doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to open a terminal) **does not work**.

After digging around the github repo I found [this commit](https://github.com/dae/anki/commit/6377dd161f24dc26fee368113b11ace001ff02af) though. Which could suggest that the problem is something to do with the mesa driver.

I would have commented instead of answering but I don't have enough rep and this program just wasted a day of my life thus I want to help others not do the same.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to implement this solution. Please cite the relevant instructions of external resources *inline* instead of just linking to them. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)